# Multiple file Upload with jersey facing issue with mediatype

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

issue with getting mediatype when multiple files are uploading with jersey `FormDataMultiPart` as the form data key name is "file" with multiple files

code as below

```
@FormDataParam("envelope") String envelope, FormDataMultiPart multipartFile)

    List<FormDataBodyPart> fbPart = multipartFile.getFields("file");

    for(FormDataBodyPart fbDataPart : fbPart){
        FormDataContentDisposition fileDispo =  fbDataPart.getFormDataContentDisposition();
        System.out.println("Content Dispo : "+ fileDispo);
        System.out.println("fileName1 : "+ fileDispo.getFileName());
        System.out.println("file mediaType1 : " + fbDataPart.getMediaType());
    }
```

Result :

```
fileName1 : emp-nt-04-10-15%20(1).doc
file mediaType1 : application/pdf

fileName1 : 29.pdf
file mediaType1 : application/msword

fileName1 : springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar
file mediaType1 : application/octet-stream
```

as in the output the file mediatype is interchanging when i upload multiple files, if i check with single file everything fine.

Comment: Maybe the file extension is causing this, I don't know. But you can set the mediatype before deserializing it. If you want you can do `bodyPart.setMediaType(...)`. `bodyPart.getEntityAs(...)`

Comment: Or maybe I'm misundersanding your question. Really, your problem is not that clearly stated. Mind rephrasing?

Answer (score 0):

at last found the issue there no issue with jersey file upload the issue with my postman client of 
Version 3.2.20 (packaged) OS: win
Architecture: x86-32
Native client architecture: x86-64

with this when you upload the files the stream is not in order because of that it causing issue.